# How to create layout which support different screen size?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have already created a layout for the different screen such as default, normal, large, and small but it does not work when I run this app in different screen size emulators

so what should I do to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: share you xml code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588639/do-i-need-to-change-my-xml-code-for-supporting-all-screen-size-android-devices

Comment: this is my xml code So can you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: @Neelpatel answerd your question in the XML link you provided. I hope it helps.