# Do I need to change my xml code for supporting all screen size android devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have created layout for different screen size and this is my xml code for default layout 
but so any one please tell me what I should do to support my layout for any screen size android devices.

do I need to change my xml code?
or 
just I need to modify my xml code ?

please tell me so I can solve my problem

> xlm

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Login"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nice"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:hint="Username"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyleNormal">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewForgotPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/ForgotPassword"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Login"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/To_Join_With"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/Click_here"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support different screen sizes, then use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Dimension for different sizes of elements for different screens. If you need a different layout of elements on different screens, then you can create different xml files for different screen sizes [Android layouts for different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962692/android-layouts-for-different-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

I edited you XML so it may be a good start for learning how to use ConstraintLayout. Check a tutorial for ConstraintLayout (constraintlayout.com)

1. Don't use match_parent with ConstraintLayout we only have 0dp (match_constraint) and wrap_conent
2. Don't mess up the XML with unneccessary nested ViewGroups (LinearLayout)
3. When using margin or padding best to use numbers based on 8 (8 -  16 - 24 - 32 - ...)
4. Using a CardView for button is wrong, check MaterialButton documents at material.io

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Login"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_loginMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/nice"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutUsername"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_loginMessage">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:counterTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyleNormal"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/ErrorStyleNormal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayoutUsername"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewForgotPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@string/ForgotPassword"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/materialButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:icon="@color/yourArrowIcon"
            app:iconGravity="start"
            android:text="yourText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewForgotPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_join"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/To_Join_With"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/materialButton" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Click_here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_join" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```